Setting flexible spacing increments for margins based off root em variable
Currently I have a theme files that looks something like this:
export const Theme = {
  
  //Primary is accessible on white or beige bckgrnd, others are not //
  primary: "#036c5f",
  secondary: "#f89d3e",
  primaryGreen: "#083D35",
  accentGreen: "#62CDB1",
  midGreen: "#0E6C5F",

  // Background and neutral colours //
  backgroundBeige: "#F6F5F1",
  lightGray: "#eaeaea",
  ultraLightGray: "#fafafa",
  gray: "#d0d3d4",
  charcoalGrey: "#636363",
  darkBlack: "#242627",
  lightBlack: "#2d2f31",

  // Focus State colours //
  focusBlue: "#2C81FF",
  
  borderRadius: "8px",
  borderRadiusElliptic: "32px 0px 32px 0px",
  boxShadow:
    "0 0 0 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%), 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%), 0 12px 24px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);",
  boxShadowMedium: "0 8px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.12)",
  border: "1px solid #eaeaea",
  breakpointPhone: "299px",
  breakpointPhoneM: "420px",
  breakpointPhoneL: "620px",
  breakpointTablet: "899px",
  breakpointLaptop: "1024px",
  breakpointLaptopBig: "1224px",
};

export default Theme;

I want to structure my spacing off the root variable (set in em units) like this CSS example within the above theme file:
:root {
    --space-unit: 1em;
    --space-xxs:  calc(0.25 * var(--space-unit));
    --space-xs:   calc(0.5 * var(--space-unit));
    --space-sm:   calc(0.75 * var(--space-unit));
    --space-md:   calc(1.25 * var(--space-unit));
    --space-lg:   calc(2 * var(--space-unit));
    --space-xl:   calc(3.25 * var(--space-unit));
    --space-xxl:  calc(5.25 * var(--space-unit));
}

BUT I want to write this in javascript within the above theme.js file.
What syntax should I use?
Any help would be appreciated.
I've tried the following:
spaceUnit: "1em";
spaceXS: "calc(0.5 * var(--spaceUnit))",
spaceS: "calc(1 * var(--spaceUnit))",
spaceM: "calc(1.5 * var(--spaceUnit))",
spaceL: "calc(2 * var(--spaceUnit))",
spaceXL: "calc(3.5 * var(--spaceUnit))",

BUT I don't think I have it right.
I'm referencing it in pages like so:
<div style={{ marginTop: Theme.spaceXL }}>
    <AccordionSection accordionData={accordionTop} />
</div>


You can use a combination of getters and getComputedStyle.


const Theme = {
  getRootStyle(variableName) {
    return getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue(variableName);
  },

  get spaceXL() {
    return this.getRootStyle('--space-xl');
  },
  
  //Primary is accessible on white or beige bckgrnd, others are not //
  primary: "#036c5f",
  secondary: "#f89d3e",
  primaryGreen: "#083D35",
  accentGreen: "#62CDB1",
  midGreen: "#0E6C5F",

  // Background and neutral colours //
  backgroundBeige: "#F6F5F1",
  lightGray: "#eaeaea",
  ultraLightGray: "#fafafa",
  gray: "#d0d3d4",
  charcoalGrey: "#636363",
  darkBlack: "#242627",
  lightBlack: "#2d2f31",

  // Focus State colours //
  focusBlue: "#2C81FF",
  
  borderRadius: "8px",
  borderRadiusElliptic: "32px 0px 32px 0px",
  boxShadow:
    "0 0 0 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%), 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%), 0 12px 24px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);",
  boxShadowMedium: "0 8px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.12)",
  border: "1px solid #eaeaea",
  breakpointPhone: "299px",
  breakpointPhoneM: "420px",
  breakpointPhoneL: "620px",
  breakpointTablet: "899px",
  breakpointLaptop: "1024px",
  breakpointLaptopBig: "1224px",
};

console.log('spaceXL:', Theme.spaceXL)
:root {
  --space-unit: 1rem;
  --space-xl: calc(3.25 * var(--space-unit));
}




Thank you so much, this seems to be working! Appreciate the help :)
